# Converting files to digital image failing with "tile cannot extend outside image"

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to recreate some of the work from the blog posting http://sarvamblog.blogspot.com/2013/04/clustering-malware-corpus.html

```
import itertools
import glob
import numpy,scipy, os, array
from scipy.misc import imsave

for filename in list(glob.glob('file/*.file')):
    f = open(filename,'rb');
        #just want to make sure I get the right file'
    print filename
    ln = os.path.getsize(filename); # length of file in bytes
    width = 256;
    rem = ln%width; 
    a = array.array("B"); # uint8 array
    a.fromfile(f,ln-rem);
    f.close(); 
    g = numpy.reshape(a,(len(a)/width,width));
    g = numpy.uint8(g);
    fpng = filename + ".png"
        # make sure the png process and everything else is going'
    print fpng
    scipy.misc.imsave(fpng,g);`
```

And although this runs great on 1 or 2 files, I run into problems on once I expand to dozens

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 14, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/misc/pilutil.py", line 120, in imsave
   im = toimage(arr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/misc/pilutil.py", line 183, in toimage
    image = Image.fromstring('L',shape,bytedata.tostring())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1797, in fromstring
    im.fromstring(data, decoder_name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 590, in fromstring
    d.setimage(self.im)
  ValueError: tile cannot extend outside image
```

I assume that my issue is with not either A: closing the scipy.misc.imsave or B: not resetting the arrarys. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It may also be caused by the image itself being corrupt? Print out each filename before processing it to see if it consistently fails on a particular one. Then try just that one on its own

Comment: have you tried to use bitmap images?

Comment: Do you mean the output or the input> The files themselves are actually binary executables.  The goal is to  create an image file that is a visual representative of the executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to figure it out with a try/except loop.  Once I did that I was able to determine that only certain files were canceling out. These files were extremely small (125 bytes). My assumption is that they were too small to create all the info needed for scipy

Answer (score 1):

im.crop(box) ⇒ image
The box is a 4-tuple defining the left, upper, right, and lower pixel coordinate.

when lower is small than upper in my code,this error has happened.